# Subtracting two dates in different formats in R

Tags: r, date

I'm trying to add a new column with date calculations. The calculation to be entered in the new column is variable MaturityDate minus today's date. 
MaturityDate in my dataset is in MM/DD/YYYY format and today's date entered with Sys.Date() is in a different format, which I think is what's giving me trouble when calculating. 
help please!

Comment: Make sure both values are proper POSIX date values in R (see `?DateTimeClasses`). Sounds right now like one of them may be a factor or string. But you really need to post a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data that closely resembles your own so we can see what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

Use package lubridate to make date manipulation easy.

```
library(lubridate)  
somedate <- mdy("3/14/2015")  
today <- now()  
somedate - today
```

Answer (score 0):

I would convert the dates to a single format to be sure.

```
date.to.numeric <- function(x) as.numeric(strptime(x,'%m/%d/%Y'))
now <- function() as.numeric(strptime(Sys.Date(),'%Y-%m-%d'))
```

With this you get time difference in seconds using

```
date.to.numeric(date) - now()
```

Also look at `as.POSIXct` for more date formatting if you wanted something different (e.g., difference in calendar months).

Answer (score 0):

When your dataframe is called `YourDataFrame` and your new column with the desired result should be called `newCol`:

```
YourDataFrame$newCol <- as.Date(MaturityDate, "%m/%d/%Y") - Sys.Date()
```

Answer (score 0):

Something that works well for me is using a combination of `library(dplyr)` and `library(lubridate)`like so:

```
dataset <-dataset %>% 
    mutate(MaturityDate=mdy(MaturityDate), #make sure to say what the format is first
    Sys.Date=mdy(Sys.Date)) %>%
    mutate(difference=as.numeric(difftime (Sys.Date, MaturityDate, units = "days")))
```

This gives something like so:

```
head(dataset,2)

> MaturityDate     Sys.Date     difference
> 2018-05-05      2018-05-26    50
> 2018-06-06      2018-06-10    48
```